# PHP Trim inside function

Tags: php, function, syntax, syntax-error

I have the following simple PHP script:

```
<?php

    function generate($test_var, trim($test_var2)) {
        echo $test_var2;
    }

    generate('value 1', ' value2');

?>
```

It's giving the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE 
in ** on line 3
```

I can't figure out why trim can't be used in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply can't call a function inside the argument list of the definition of another function<sup>*</sup>. Perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```
function generate($test_var, $test_var2) {
    $test_var2 = trim($test_var2);
    echo $test_var2;
}
```

<sup>* Note that you can use the [`array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) language construct when declaring the default value of parameter, although this isn't a function.</sup>

**Further Reading**

- [Function arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 3):

Another function is not valid *within the list of parameters in a function's definition* in PHP. The operative words being **within the list of parameters in a function's definition**; you can read about the structure of a function here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Having said that, when invoking a function as mentioned below in the comments by [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579/p-s-w-g) you can pass a function as an argument in most cases as a [*callback*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

E.g.

**Valid:**

```
function foo($bar, $baz) {
   // Do something
}

...
foo('Hello', trim('World '));
```

**Invalid:**

```
function foo($bar, trim($baz)) {
   // Do something
}

...
foo('Hello', 'World ');
```

---

Simply put:

> PHP supports passing arguments by value (the default), passing by reference, and default argument values. Variable-length argument lists are also supported, see also the function references for func_num_args(), func_get_arg(), and func_get_args() for more information.

Comment: I think the language of this answer may confuse some readers. You *can* pass a function as an argument to another function (see [callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)), but you can't invoke the function in inside the arguments list.

Comment: Fair, although I think that "in a function's definition" clarifies it. I'll re-word to make it less confusing.